# Need to find regex for flight number

Tags: java, regex

The airline designator consists of two alphanumeric characters (Any letter from the English alphabet or a digit) followed by an optional letter.  The flight number consists of between 1 to 4 numeric characters (digit) and an optional one letter operational suffix.  All characters are in uppercase.

This is my regex so far:

```
(?<!([A-Z0-9]))(([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\\d|\\d[A-Z])\\s?\\d{3,4})(?:\\D)
```

This doesn't work for the following outputs:

```
IEL2
9AI0923
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Translating your description directly into a regex, you'd get `[A-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z]?([0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]?)`. Yours is significantly more complicated. Are there more restrictions on a flight number that aren't in your description?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description, you can use this regex:

```
^[A-Z\d]{2}[A-Z]?\d{1,4}[A-Z]?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ftY7K/1)

There is no need to use any lookbehind or lookahead.

In Java use:

```
final String re = "^[A-Z\\d]{2}[A-Z]?\\d{1,4}[A-Z]?$";
```

Comment: Why bother with `^` and `$`?  You don't need these for matching.

Comment: IMO it is better to be explicit though `matches()` method doesn't need it. Some readers may use this regex in other languages like PHP, Javascript where `^` and `$` is needed.

Comment: This regex is as per the requirements defined in the question and `A1B2` fulfills that requirement. OP can tell us better if there are additional or different requirements.

Comment: I overlooked that can be all digits thing. Not that I have ever seen such flight numbers.